# Filter unwanted JSON data stored in a Python Variable

Tags: python, json

Currently I am pulling data from an API that is in JSON format. I parse this dataframe using ‘json.loads’ into a python variable, where I then upload this data to a connecting MYSQL database.

The issue I am encountering is that the JSON data stored in ‘employeed_parsed’ as detailed below, has a chance of incorrect data coming through.

```
# Parse json data into python variable
employee_parsed = json.loads(data2)


# Parse the observations values, as we will use this to remove the spaces in the excel file
emp_data = employee_parsed['ObservationValues']
```

If incorrect data comes in for a given ‘Timestamp’, the key; ‘Good’ is set to False instead of True. In my python code how can I filter out any of the JSON data stored in the python variable where ‘Good’ is set to False.

**Example of JSON data structure stored in python variable**

```
[{'Timestamp': '2021-05-03T05:29:41Z', 'Value': '286.958435', 'UnitsAbbreviation': '', 'Good': True, 'Questionable': False, 'Substituted': False, 'Annotated': False}, {'Timestamp': '2021-05-03T05:58:05Z', 'Value': '291.536224',..............
```

**When 'Good' is set the False, the following data is retrieved in 'Value' which is undesired:**

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{\r\n  "Name": "Calc Failed",\r\n  "Value": 249,\r\n  "IsSystem": true\r\n}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to clean up the `emp_data` list by removing observation dictionaries whose "Good" value is false. There are multiple ways to do this, a simple one would be:

`emp_data_cleaned = [observation for observation in emp_data if observation["Good"]]`

Alternatively, you could use the `filter` function, which might be more efficient if you don't want to compute the result right away:

`emp_data_cleaned  = filter(lambda observation: observation["Good"], emp_data)`